# Selenium(Python): sleep vs explicit wait

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape flight information by airpot, my code looks like this:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common import NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True);
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options)
driver.get("https://www.flightradar24.com/airport/tun/arrivals") # i want to filter arrival flights
ignored_exceptions = (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5,ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions)
try:
    consent = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]'))) 
    #handles the pop up window by clicking on consent
    consent.click()
except:
    print('problem at pop up page')
info = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'li[class="airport__flight-list-item border-b-2 delay-300 border-white w-full"]'))) 
# we select all flights 
for i in info: # iterate through the flights and only process those starting with TU
    wait_i = WebDriverWait(i, 5, ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions)
    Flightnumber = wait_i.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[class="truncate text-sm text-gray-900"]'))).text
    if Flightnumber[:2] == 'TU': 
        drop_down_button = wait_i.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[class="px-1"]'))) 
        drop_down_button.click()    # we click the little arrow at the right to get the flight 
        details = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div[class="mx-2 grid grid-cols-24"]'))).text  
        # we wait for the text of the drop down to load and then we print it                         
        print(details)
```

This code throws an error after a few flights:

```
`StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: stale element not found at    info = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div[class="mx-2 grid grid-cols-24"]').text`
```

Which is confusing me because I added such exception to the ignore list and the script 'should' theoretically wait before throwing the error.(I changed the timeout to 50s and same result) I tried swapping explicit wait with implicit wait and the result is also still the same.

So I just deleted all the explicit waits inside the for loop and just added a time.sleep(1) and now the whole code runs perfectly but I have no idea why ?

```
for i in info:
    Flightnumber = i.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[class="truncate text-sm text-gray-900"]').text
    if Flightnumber[:2] == 'TU':
        drop_down_button = i.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[class="px-1"]')
        drop_down_button.click()
        t.sleep(1)
        details = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div[class="mx-2 grid grid-cols-24"]').text
        print(details)
```

Shouldn't the explicit wait avoid the crash and wait for the element to load before trying to access it ? what is waiting 1 second inside the loop manually doing that the explicit wait can't do ?

Thank you very much

I expected the explicit wait to work the same way the time.sleep(1) is working

Comment: Stale Element is thrown when running the .text method of the element... that's outside of the wait.  The error you show doesn't seem to match the code.  Maybe that's just a typo?... assuming it is, the state of that element is changing between the .click() method and the .text, which will make it's reference stale when .text is called on it.  (remember the wait poll will exit when the element is present... that could be as soon as 0-1/2 second) The sleep is enough to prevent that.

Comment: Sorry about that, I just noticed I was missing another import, I added it and retested it and it's now reproducing the error consistently.
Thank you for the explanation, I can at least envision what's going on behind the scenes now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StaleElementReferenceException` is happened, because your element is not exist anymore.

Site renders it's data async. When you click on dropdown button, new details are not rendered immediately, so periodically you get old details element.
Next moment new details are rendered, but as far as you got line old `WebElement` object, getting props of not existing element results in this error.

That's the answer why `sleep` helped - it gave 1 second wait for re-render. However, it's not the best solution. It's better to wait for something real that would prevent from getting object before re-rendering.

For example, writing function `wait_for_values_not_equal` that checks that element text values are not equal previous value. When you clicking on another flight, you expect that text of the flight data would be different. When it is - it's guaranteed that you got new flight.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import time

def wait_for_values_not_equal(value_func, value, timeout=10, interval=0.5):
    start_time = time.time()

    while value_func() == value:
        if time.time() - start_time > timeout:
            raise TimeoutError("Timeout: Value did not change within the specified time.")
        time.sleep(interval)

    return value_func() != value

def get_details_text():
    try:
        return wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div[class="mx-2 grid grid-cols-24"]'))).text
    except StaleElementReferenceException:
        return None

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.flightradar24.com/airport/tun/arrivals")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
try:
    consent = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]')))
    #handles the pop up window by clicking on consent
    consent.click()
except:
    print('problem at pop up page')
info = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'li[class="airport__flight-list-item border-b-2 delay-300 border-white w-full"]')))
for i in info: 
    flightnumber = wait_i.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[class="truncate text-sm text-gray-900"]'))).text
    details_text = None
    if flightnumber[:2] == 'TU':
        drop_down_button = wait_i.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[class="px-1"]')))
        drop_down_button.click()
        wait_for_values_not_equal(get_details_text,  details_text)

        details_text = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div[class="mx-2 grid grid-cols-24"]'))).text
        print(details_text)
```

Note: Selenium is not the best tool for your case. It's better to catch request with the flights and parse the response.

Comment: Thank you for your response Yaro. That actually makes a lot of sense.
But this makes me think how time consuming doing this for every function I might need in the future will be.
I tried finding an API call that I can exploit but I couldn't find anything. you can try yourself and see that none of the flight responses on the Network inspection has any of the details we're seeing once we click on the drop down arrow. It's all rendered on the tab somehow.

Comment: @Dimbo123 https://monosnap.com/file/6WwxvcsVqgeW6KtGy2DYtlZUPpYRqe - maybe this response contains data you need? `https://www.flightradar24.com/mobile/airlines?format=2&version=0`.
Also I'm not sure that it would work, but I found unofficial API connector library https://pypi.org/project/FlightRadarAPI/ . With Selenium it also would work, but reference to official API would be more stable and quick. Actually, you rely on frontend only when there are no way to deal with your case, using backend. :)

Comment: Unfortunately that one doesn't have any information about the scheduled/actualy departure times. I will keep looking.

I also came across that API but the main problem with it is that in order to use it to get more information about particular flights, you need to use the flight ID that flight radar uses internally and not the flight number/ callsign for example, to get flight 'BJ517' you need to pass  '31c7e5ac' as parameter to the API call (https://ibb.co/F6nRT29) I tried to figure out the function they are using to map the callsign into their native id but to no avail...